# ConstraintLayout bias ignores margin?

Tags: android, layout, margin, android-constraintlayout

I have some code that sets horizontal end-margin and also sets horizontal bias.

```
constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(R.id.myView, 1.5f);
constraintSet.applyTo(rootView);
MarginLayoutParamsCompat.setMarginEnd(
    (MarginLayoutParams) myView.getLayoutParams(), endMargin);
```

I know margin is a property of the layout (vs padding which is a property of the view itself).

So how come this code works? I mean the bias ignores the end margin?

If not - the view would have been closer to the start (bias after including the end-margin), but I see in the UI it's centered.

Answer (score 1):

Bias for *ConstraintLayout* is between 0 and 1 inclusive. In this range, the margins on the view will be respected. Your bias of *1.5f* is invalid.